# Is there a way to filter Windows Task View (or MacOS Mission Control) with a keyboard input?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, search, navigation, task-view

I'd like to be able to type something like `[win+tab], foo` to get a view of my open windows where either the window title or application name match the word `foo`.

Some years ago I used a utility, I believe written by a Microsoft developer, which was somewhat mimicking the behaviour of OSX Expose at the time, but also with this particular feature (actually, I'd like this in MacOS as well). I don't remember the name, but it's long since deprecated now.

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for (and which I've been looking for for some time now), but I've noticed that using Microsoft Keyboard and Mouse Center (MKMC) you can assign to special buttons of some Microsoft mices (I managed to do this with Sculpt mouse) the function "Filtered Task View" which does just that (App Expose). I have tried with the Surface kbd, but MKMC doesn't seem to recognize it. Who knows? You may be able to do this with some other MS kbds...

Comment: I don't find the filtered task view does what I want; it only searches some small subset of things. I think I want it to use open Window titles instead / as well. When I try to use it, it only seems to find e.g. some Photoshop documents I'd opened in the past rather than a VSCode or browser window that's open now. I could see it being useful, but at the moment it falls short in that it requires a mouse click (Mouse and Kb Center didn't help me either, thanks for the suggestion though) and doesn't seem to register anything from the software I mostly use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Today I wrote a Windows program that does exactly that: [activatewindow](https://github.com/mardukbp/activatewindow).

It is an executable that wraps a PowerShell script, which retrieves the list of open windows and uses [heatseeker](https://github.com/rschmitt/heatseeker) to filter the list. If the selected window is minimized then it becomes maximized. Otherwise it is raised to the foreground.

The essence of the program is the `Get-Process` cmdlet:

```
$procs=@{}

Get-Process | Where { ($_.MainWindowTitle -ne "") } | 
foreach { $procs[$_.MainWindowTitle] = $_.MainWindowHandle }
```

together with the Win32 API functions `SetForegroundWindow`, `IsIconic` and `ShowWindowAsync`.

In macOS it should be possible to replace the PowerShell script with an AppleScript program.

Comment: Sounds promising, I look forward to trying it. I was hoping perhaps for something a bit more graphical/ interactive, so as you type you see the set of displayed windows change in real-time, but your utility seems useful anyway and perhaps my question didn't express that very well.

Comment: Yesterday I improved it. Now it lists all windows belonging to a process and not only the main window. What you are looking for is doable. You need to write a filter such that after a key press event it waits long enough so that you can enter a few chars before it calls SetForegroundWindow.